# Present UIViewController one after another

Tags: iphone

UIToolbar button on the `MainViewController` presents `UIViewController`, now i want to display multiple `UIViewControllers` one after the other via this button.What is the best way to do this.

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{ 
PageOneViewController *viewController = [[[PageOneViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

}
```

when button is pressed it displays this `UIViewController` now right after this `UIViewController` i want to present multiple `UIViewControllers` one after the other.

Any ideas please.

Comment: You mean like a flip book, where multiple views come on screen one after another, each one replacing the last? Animated?

Comment: There is no user interface involved going from one uiviewcontroller to another. But yes current uiviewcontroller will be replace with the new uiviewcontroller. NStimer will be there to load uiviewcontroller after 5 seconds or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to display view controllers A,B,C by tapping on main view controller's tool bar button. To do so write

```
 [self presentModalViewController:a animated:YES];
```

on button action. In A's viewDidAppear: method, write

```
 [self presentModalViewController:b animated:YES];
```

Writing same for all view controllers will display viewControllers one after another.

Comment: If he wants to fire off the new views every 5 seconds with a timer, this approach will not work.